# SharePoint add list item using REST fails on field of type=SP.FieldUrlValue

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint

I am inserting a new item in a custom list using the jQuery $.Ajax function and the SharePoint 2013 REST and receive an error 400 (Bad Request).

I pass the following JSON (stringified before the call) as the data to the REST invocation:

```
jSONitem =
{
    '__metadata': { "type": "SP.Data.TransmittalDocsListItem" },
    'Title': $scope.myTransmittal.name,
    'TransmittalName': $scope.myTransmittal.name,
    'TransmittalIdInList': $scope.myTransmittal.id,
    'TransmittalLink': {
        'Description': $scope.myTransmittal.description,
        'Url': $scope.myTransmittal.url
    },
    'DocumentName': data.FileLeafRef,
    'DocumentIdInList': data.Id,
    'DocumentLink': {
        '__metadata': { "type": "SP.FieldUrlValue" },
        'Description': data.OData__dlc_DocIdUrl.Description,
        'Url': data.OData__dlc_DocIdUrl.Url
    }
};
```

If I just remove the 2 objects that are my Links (SP.FieldUrlValue), the call succeeds and the item is added. I have tried everything I could think of, but I am stuck. For instance, I removed the _Metadata from the JSON with the same result.

This is the sample JSON that worked... I could save this as Single line of text to get a quick fix, but this should work!

```
jSONitem =
{
    '__metadata': { "type": "SP.Data.TransmittalDocsListItem" },
    'Title': $scope.myTransmittal.name,
    'TransmittalName': $scope.myTransmittal.name,
    'DocumentName': data.FileLeafRef,
    'DocumentIdInList': data.Id,
};
```

Comment: I figured out what was wrong... The 2 SharePoint URL fields have special pattern for their internal name. For instance, the DocumentLink field has the following: DisplayName="DocumentLink", InternalName="DocumentLink0", StaticName="DocumentLink". So I needed to change the 'DocumentLink': bu 'DocumentLink0' and it worked.